# How can I test if a command is followed by an argument?

Tags: macros

Imagine I have two commands defined as

```
\def\witharg#1{something with #1}
\def\without{something without arg}
```

and I want to define a new command `\mycmd` that behaves as `\witharg` if it's followed by an argument (not necessarily enclosed in braces), and behaves like `\without` if it is not followed by an argument. In fact, the later case can only be true if `\mycmd` is followed by the token `}`. To make things slightly more clear, I want

```
{\mycmd\token\mycmd}
```

to expand to something similar to the expansion of

```
{\witharg{\token}\without}
```

How can I achieve this?

Note that, in fact, trying to evaluate something like `{\witharg}` fails with TeX complaining that there is an extra `}`, i.e. the argument to `\witharg` is missing.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that is strictly in basic TeX? I.E. is LaTeX allowed?

Comment: `tex-guts` is a really ugly term to use. Can we use `tex-only` or `plain-tex` instead?

Comment: I was trying, you can re-tag of course :)

Comment: @SSharpie, I was looking for a TeX answer, but a LaTeX one would also be welcome

Comment: I thought the consensus was `tex-core`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Whenever you need to check what comes next after a macro, the primitive to use is generally `\futurelet` (see TeX by Topic for a good reference). In this case, you'd write something like

```
\def\mycmd{%
  \futurelet\mytoken\myargparse
}
```

which will `\let` the following token to `\mytoken` and then expand `\myargparse`. Define `\myargparse` to be conditional on what `\mytoken` is, and that's it:

```
\def\myargparse{%
  \ifx\mytoken\closingbracetoken
    \expandafter\without
  \else
    \expandafter\witharg
  \fi
}
\let\closingbracetoken=}
```

Finally, check that it works:

```
\def\witharg#1{something with #1}
\def\without{something without arg}
\def\token{TOK}
{\mycmd\token\mycmd}
```

Comment: More or less what I was about to write :-)

Comment: You would have written your explanations more clearly `:)`

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I found about `\futurelet` but somehow I couldn't figure out how to test for `}` or put all of it together. This works nicely!

Answer (score 3):

`xparse` can test for explicit brace-delimited arguments (or other delimiters, see [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse

\NewDocumentCommand\mycmd{g}{%
\IfValueTF{#1}{(something with #1)}{(something without arg)}%
}

\def\token{TOK}
\begin{document}

\mycmd{Hello}

\mycmd

{\mycmd\token\mycmd}

Blah, \mycmd{Hello}, blah, \mycmd, blah

\end{document}
```

[image: compiled output]

Comment: but in the `{\mycmd\token\mycmd}` case, I wanted `\token` to be used as an argument to the first `\mycmd`. Here it seems that the argument is taken only if enclosed by braces?

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro: Correct, This approach requires braces when you want to pass an argument, Will's `\futurelet` approach requires braces when you do not want to pass an argument. Use whichever you find more natural (for my code, I find the "braces when arg wanted" semantics more natural).