# How to use \futurelet to define optional parameters

Tags: tex-core

I am trying to create a simple macro using TeX with optional parameters:

```
 \elide[options]{}
```

I understand a common way is to use `\futurelet`. So far the code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\def\elidebefore[#1]#2{[$\ldots$] #2}
\def\elideafter#1{#1$\ldots$}

\def\elide {%
\futurelet\ifoptions
    \choosemacro
}

% The \choosemacro, based on
% the lookahead of \elide, calls
% either \elidebefore or \elideafter 


\def\choosemacro{%
 \ifx\ifoptions [%
     \let\choice = \elidebefore 
 \else
    \let\choice = \elideafter
 \fi
\choice
}

Testing \elide[b]{Lorem ipsum}

\elide{Lorem Ipsum}

\elide[b]{Lorem ipsum}

\end{document}
```

This works ... but since I am only checking if the square bracket exists and switching to either macro1 or macro2 `elide[]{}`  will work with anything in-between the square brackets. How, can I extend the macro to read the letters between the square brackets?

Is there a predefined LaTeX macro that one can use? (I know about `keyval`, but I just prefer to do this with basic commands).

Comment: I am a bit confused over what you mean by extending the macro to read the letters between the square brackets. You do have the text between the brackets available as #1, after all. You only need to use it in the body of your macro.

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen Thanks for the answer and the comment. If you try \elide[]{test} it works. I am trying to extend the macro so that one would be able to parse something like \elide[a,b,c]{} or \elide{}. I am also trying to understand the workings of \futurelet a bit better.

Comment: Okay, but what do you want \elide[a,b,c]{} to do?

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen \elide[b,s]{text} ->  [...]text (b=before,s=square brackets), \elide[a,b]{text}-> text[...], but primarily I am trying to relearn to program TeX/LaTeX, for an application I am building! \futurelet just tied my brain in knots:)

Comment: Not really what you're trying to do. But for an example of an application of `\futurelet` see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-can-i-test-if-a-command-is-followed-by-an-argument).

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides: I don't follow what you're trying to do. Where did the a and b in your response to Harald get used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are only trying to define a macro with an optional argument, `\newcommand` will do that for you:

```
\newcommand{\elide}[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
    #2$\ldots$%
  \else $\ldots$ #2\fi}
```

should work the same as your macro, except it may behave oddly if you give it an optional argument beginning with `\relax`.

Comment: This is a really bizarre use of an optional argument. The value is irrelevant. If this were the use case, I'd say go with a `*` instead.

Comment: Agreed. But assuming that I want to use the optional argument, in the case where it is present, and do something entirely different where it is not, this technique has worked well for me.

Comment: @TH. of course, then `\def\elide{\@ifnextchar*{<star-code>\@gobble}{<non-star-code>}}` works just good (of course with `\makeat(letter|other)`).