# Reading datafile entry by entry

Tags: pstricks, datatool

In order to use pstricks in a certain fashion, I would like to access a datafile line by line, inside a multido loop. For example, let's say my file is called Datafile.dat. It contains the (x,y) coordinates of say, 20 points. I would like something like

```
\multido{\iA=0+1}{20}{%
\psdot(Datafile.dat(\iA,1),Datafile.dat(\iA,2))
}
```

I know there exists functions to do this, but my emphasis is on being able to access the datafile element by element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might do it for you.

Let's say the dataA.txt file contained the following space-separated data:

```
.15 12   13 14
.20 22   23 24
.25 45.6 33 Ending
```

Then this code can read the file using the defined `\readdef` command (like dataA in the example) or you can cut and paste it into the file (like dataB in the example)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
%
\newcounter{index}
\newcounter{row}
\newcounter{col}
%
\newcommand\readArray[3]{%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \setcounter{row}{1}%
  \setcounter{col}{0}%
  \getargs{#1}%
  \whiledo{\value{index} < \narg}{%
    \addtocounter{index}{1}%
%    \arabic{index}:~%
    \addtocounter{col}{1}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{col} > #3}%
      {\addtocounter{row}{1}%
       \addtocounter{col}{-#3}}%
      {}%
%    \arabic{row}-\arabic{col}\\%
    \expandafter\edef\csname#2X\roman{row}X\roman{col}\endcsname%
      {\expandafter\csname arg\roman{index}\endcsname}%
  }%
}
%
\newcommand\Arrayij[3]{%
  \setcounter{row}{#2}
  \setcounter{col}{#3}
  \csname#1X\roman{row}X\roman{col}\endcsname
}
%
\newcommand\readdef[2]{%
\catcode\endlinechar=10\relax%
\def#2{}%
\newread\file%
\openin\file=#1%
\loop\unless\ifeof\file%
    \read\file to\fileline % Reads a line of the file into \fileline%
    % Do something with \fileline%
    \edef#2{#2\fileline}%
\repeat%
\closein\file%
\catcode\endlinechar=5\relax%
}
%
\begin{document}
%
\readdef{dataA.txt}{\dataA}
%  The \readdef produces the equivalent result to
%  \edef\dataA{
%  .15 12   13 14
%  .20 22   23 24
%  .25 45.6 33 Ending
%  }
%
\def\dataB{%
B.15 B12 B13 B14
B.20 B22 B23 B24
B.25 B32 B33 BEnding
}
%
% This says to read the variable \dataA, stick it into an "array"
% called arA with a 4-column width
\readArray{\dataA}{arA}{4}
\readArray{\dataB}{arB}{4}
\noindent
The data in the 3,2 position of the dataA file is \Arrayij{arA}{3}{2}\\
The data in the 3,4 position of dataB is \Arrayij{arB}{3}{4}
\end{document}
```

The `\readArray` command takes the space separated data and sticks it into an array, and then you can call back individual array elements with `\Arrayij` invocations.  It's currently defined for 2-D (x,y) data input, but it could be adapted for 3-D, for example.

(As an aside, the stringstrings routine used is `\getargs`.  If slow speed for large data is an issue, faster versions of that routine have been put forth by various bright sx users at [Parsing strings containing diacritical marks (macros?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101604/parsing-strings-containing-diacritical-marks-macros).)

Note: edited so that `\readdef` could be used more than once without overwriting itself.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I will adapt this to 3D data :)

Comment: @Mathusalem, I added a percent on the line `\def\dataB{%`.  While stringstrings didn't need it, the alternate versions of `getargs` that I cited do.  And it's just good practice to do it.

Comment: @Mathusalem This solution approach is codified as the `readarray` package, now available on CTAN