# csv data and multido

Tags: pstricks, csv, multido

I am making a card with properties of Periodic Table of Elements. I wish had the mass number, like this using `pstricks`:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a1paper]{article}
    \usepackage[a1paper,margin=0cm]{geometry} %fija los márgenes
    
    \newcommand{\carta}[2]{
        \begin{pspicture}(-2,-3)(2,3)
            % colores fondo
            \pspolygon[linearc=.2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,linewidth=.1pt](-2,0)(-2,3)(2,3)(2,0)
            \pspolygon[linearc=.2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray!75,linewidth=.1pt](-2,0)(-2,-3)(2,-3)(2,0)
            %\psframe*[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,linewidth=2pt](-2,0)(2,3)
            % línea divisoria
            \psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=3pt]{-}(-2,0)(2,0)
            \pspolygon[linearc=.2,linewidth=2pt](-2,-3)(-2,3)(2,3)(2,-3)
            % tipo de carta
            \uput[d](0,3){\parbox{3cm}{\centering\large{\textrm#1}}}
            \uput[u]{180}(0,-3){\parbox{3cm}{\centering\large{\textrm#1}}}
            % valor de carta
            \rput(0,1){\Huge{#2}}
            \rput{180}(0,-1){\Huge{#2}}
        \end{pspicture}
    }
    \begin{document}
\carta{Símbolo elemento}{\ECFPookie{H}}
\carta{Nombre elemento}{\ECFPookie{\large{Hidrógeno}}}
\multido{}{94}{
\carta{Tipo de elemento}{\color{white}{Metal}}
}
\multido{}{17}{
\carta{Tipo de elemento}{\color{brown}{No Metal}}
}
\multido{}{7}{
\carta{Tipo de elemento}{\color{blue}{Gas Noble}}
}

\multido{\i=1+1}{118}{
\carta{Número atómico $Z$}{$\i$}
\carta{Cantidad de protones}{$\i$}
\carta{Cantidad de electrones}{$\i$}
}
\multido{\i=0+1}{118}{
\carta{Cantidad de neutrones}{$\i$} 
}
\end{document}
```

works fine for now, but the mass number, names and neutron there aren't sequencied like proton and electron. For the neutrons we have: 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 10, ie almost aleatory.

I think if I make a csv data for all, because it would be easier to write. The problem is that I do not know if is possible to link `multido` and csv file, so that I read the cycle from there.

Writing one by one for 118 elements, including names and symbols, would be tedious and a lot of code.

Comment: Related? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102619/47128